Android (kotlin) API 33 permissions reading external device (USB)
Trying to communicate and read out data from an external device (USB) but keep getting open failed: EACCES (Permission denied).
Currently i'm requesting these permissions
<!--    for API level 32 and below-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!--    both are for API level 33 and above-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>

And then run through them with an OnButtonClick. API 33 > I see the result in my app that it got the Photos&Videos permission, also got a Toast popup saying it got those permissions.
Then i go to the next stage/button click to communicate with the USB device and request USB device permission:
    fun requestUSBPermission() {
            try{
                val usbDeviceList = manager.deviceList
                if (usbDeviceList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val device = usbDeviceList.values.first()

                    val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
                    manager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No USB device connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                errorText.setText(e.toString())
                println(e)
            }

        }

I get a pop requesting if its ok to access  and i press Ok.
Then i go on trying to read out the data but get the EACCES (Permission denied).
Quick recap of the reading data code:
    val manager = getSystemService(USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
    val usbDevice = device as UsbDevice
    val usbInterface = usbDevice.getInterface(0)
    val connection = manager.openDevice(device)
    val claimed = connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true)
    val endpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(i)
    if (endpoint.type == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK && endpoint.direction ==     UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
    val file= File("/dev/bus/usb/003/002/1/123.mp4")
    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(mp4File) 
    //This is where it crashes and throws permission exception

I'm not sure what is going wrong, or if this is even the correct way to read data from an external device

If its something like a USB drive you should just be able to use use getExternalFilesDirs and StorageManager to get the device storage volume and read files from there

getExternalFilesDirs doesnt work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getexternalfilesdirs?view=net-android-34.0
"The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives connected to handheld devices"
So what else can i do

I dont know why you are showing me microsoft documentation but I literally use that API to get stuff off of a USB flash drive so yes it does work

Wrong link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)
But still the same "The returned paths do not include transient devices, such as USB flash drives connected to handheld devices".
Also tried it myself and checked the debugger and didn't see anything of the external USB. So you must have some magic code you'd like to share?
